# How to change iOS Simulator deployment target (IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET) in React Native?

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm getting

> The iOS Simulator deployment target: 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is
>   set to 5.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is
>   8.0 to 13.5.99. (in target 'CocoaAsyncSocket' from project 'Pods').

When I open Xcode and go to General and then under Deployment Info the Target is iOS9.0 and beside is a checkbox with the word iPhone beside it.

How do I change 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'  for iOS Simulator?